# Batch conversion of Module files with XMP

Tags: shell-script, audio, conversion, ffmpeg

I have the following script to convert a big bunch of .MOD and .XM files into Wave format:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./XM.* ./MOD.*
    do
    xmp $f -d wav -o - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "$f.mp3"
done
```

But it doesn't work as expected. The program just hang up. It creates the .wav file but nothing more.(Doesn't write in it) Even the -vvv switch doesn't give any information.
The strange thing is: if I prepend "strace", it's working fine.

Any ideas/workarounds?

Comment: What if you lose the pipe and just write to a temp file and have `ffmpeg` encode that?

Comment: The problem is, that xmp doesn't respond if it's called in a shell script at all.

Comment: Run the script with `-x` to display the actual commands on stderr (e.g. `bash -x convert.sh` or place `set -x` somewhere in the script before the call to `xmp`). Or just print the commands instead of executing them (you'll have to escape the `|` of course). Then try to run the printed commands directly and get back to us with the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps xmp gets confused because stdin is not a tty? You could try:

```
xmp $f -d wav -o - </dev/null | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "$f.mp3"
```

Also, I would imagine that the order of arguments needs to be

```
xmp -d wav -o - "$f" </dev/null | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "$f.mp3"
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 with xmp 4.0.6 and avconv instead of ffmpeg, the order needs to be with the `-d wav` option later, or raw gets used

```
xmp -o - -d wav "$f" | avconv -i - -b 320k "$f.mp3"
```